# i have to draw info from three tables , i have done it but can it be done in faster query

Tags: mysql, sql

table one

```
create table bills(bill_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Person_id int , cash_credit char(10),
 amount int, advance int, final_amount int, date char(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (bill_id), FOREIGN KEY (Person_id) REFERENCES members(Person_id));
```

table two

```
create table Transactions (
 Person_id int not null, Credit int, Debit int, date char(255),
 FOREIGN KEY (Person_id) REFERENCES members(Person_id));
```

table three

```
create table members(person_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name char(50), address char(50), phone_no char(12),
 date char(255),PRIMARY KEY(person_id));
```

the final data i needed, got by the following method but slightly delayed

requested query

```
create view credit_details as  (select Person_id as id, 
sum(amount) as Credit, sum(advance) as Debit from bills 
where cash_credit = "Credit" group by id union 
select Person_id as id, sum(Credit) as  Credit,
sum(Debit) as Debit from Transactions group by Person_id);

select members.name, sum(credit) as  Credit , sum(Debit) as Debit from 
(credit_details INNER JOIN members ON credit_details.id = members.person_id) group by id;
```

Hear whats the issue is when creating view table there is slight delay in time , but got the required data from tables, but over all i need to get the final data in a single query is that possible

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use View instead you can do it in one query just by using CTE.
As below.

```
WITH CTE_credit_details
AS
(
        SELECT Person_id AS id
            ,sum(amount) AS Credit
            ,sum(advance) AS Debit
        FROM bills
        WHERE cash_credit = "Credit"
        GROUP BY id
        
        UNION
        
        SELECT Person_id AS id
            ,sum(Credit) AS Credit
            ,sum(Debit) AS Debit
        FROM Transactions
        GROUP BY Person_id
        )

SELECT members.name
    ,sum(credit) AS Credit
    ,sum(Debit) AS Debit
FROM (
    CTE_credit_details INNER JOIN members ON CTE_credit_details.id = members.person_id
    )
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'credit_details.id' in 'on clause'  i got this error

Comment: updated the code now. Please check now. Join condition was not updated to CTE table name. Now I have done that. I can't really test as I don't have sample data handy

Comment: thanks a lot save my tree days struggle

Comment: already did ,worked exactly

Answer (score 0):

Probably simpler, possibly faster:

```
select  members.name, sum(credit) as Credit , 
        sum(Debit) as Debit
    FROM  ( 
            (   SELECT  Person_id as id, sum(amount) as Credit,
                        sum(advance) as Debit
                    from  bills
                    where  cash_credit = "Credit"
                    group by  id
                    
            )
        UNION ALL
            (   SELECT  Person_id as id, sum(Credit) as Credit,
                        sum(Debit) as Debit
                    from  Transactions
                    group by  Person_id
            ) 
          ) AS u
    JOIN  members  ON u.id = members.person_id
    GROUP BY  u.id;
```